# Allow access to specific URL with one parameter and value in Nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url

I have Nginx and next URl which I cannot access to it:

```
http://www.example.com/file.php?parameter=value
```

Currently I have Nginx rules setup that are blocking access to the given example.

How can I allow this specific URL and got it working?

```
location http://www.example.com/file.php?parameter=value {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /file.php?$args;
}
```

OR:

```
location ~* http://www.example.com/file.php?parameter=value {
    allow all;
}
```

Maybe something like this?:

```
~ "^parameter=value"
```

This one is specific as is and I cannot access to it. I got 404/405 error. Does this mean that It does not exists or it is blocked somewhere before?

Thanks.

Comment: Locations shouldn't contain protocol (http/s) or domain name. Your question is really not very clear, can you please edit your question to try to explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only allow a single URL with specific parameters, you need to do a little extra than just a simple `location` block. This is because one can only match normalized URIs in `location` directives.

You can try something like this:

```
location /file.php {
    if ($arg_parameter = "value") {
        try_files /file.php$is_args$args =404;
    }
    return 404;
}
```

This `location` block matches the URI `/file.php` (the domain is matched via the `server_name` directive). Then we test if the `parameter` argument is the text `value`. If it is, then we pass processing to the PHP file.

Otherwise we return error code 404.

It might be easier for you to perform this condition checking in your PHP script.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Woow, that is the solution and now it is working. Thank You!